# How can I copy the entire line without selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wonder if there's a keyboard shortcut to copy the entire line where the cursor is without having to select it.

**NOTE:** I know how to duplicate it up and down, and how to move it too, but the problem is that sometimes I want to copy the same line of code to another different method, even to another different file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction` command ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing)). It copies either the current selection or, when nothing is selected, the whole line to the clipboard.
By default it is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on macOS).